# What will she share with another person?

Tags: meaning

**Context : Her friend gets married.** [[Link](http://www.storypick.com/things-feel-best-friend-gets-married/)]

And now [she is saying](http://www.storypick.com/things-feel-best-friend-gets-married/#attachment_6749): "Now I will have to share her with someone else."

**What will she share with the other person?**

- Memories of her friend.
- Time
- something else

Comment: does this mean now he/she will have to share her friend story to another person who doesn't know his/her friend ?

Comment: Or does this mean now she'll have to share her friend money/toys/ or any thing with another person ?

Comment: You really need to add some context.

Comment: Context : Her friend gets married.

Comment: "I will have to share her" means just that, word for word. Every word can be looked up in a dictionary of your choice. It can be a bilingual dictionary, too. You can translate the sentence word for word into your native tongue and that will be the exact meaning of the sentence in English.

Comment: Well is it her friend or her best friend? This is critical.

Comment: By the way, _convey_ is another one of the many English verbs used in the [Conduit Metaphor](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/188438/15299), which assumes that the language is the vehicle for meaning, and if the speaker put it in, listeners should be able to get it out. If they can't -- goes the story -- it's not their fault; it must be the speaker's fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, what is the context ? What do you mean by her ? Is it a real woman or a doll ? I'll assume that you meant woman.

Secondly, the way this sentence is written, it can sound offensive to the woman in question 
or to others too. Sharing a woman can have a sexual connotation. Unless you meant it that way, please avoid using the sentence as is.

I think the sentence means that the woman will not be able to help you or work with you because she now has to help another person as well. So, you can rephrase it like this -

`Now, I will not get all of her attention or time` or `Now I will get less of her time or attention`.

**EDIT -** Now that you added the context, you can say it like this - 
`Now that she is married, I won't get to spend much time with her.`

Eg. Small sister : Now that my big sister is getting married, I won't get to spend much time with her. I will miss her very much.

Comment: Thanks. I think the writer wants to convey that when her friend gets married she'll not get much of her friend time and now she'll share that time with another friend. That's why writer says "Now I will have to share her with another person"

Comment: @Sam - Yes. If you think my answer helps, then please select it. Thank you. Chenqui.